# database to diagrams

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

hi 
I have a bug database for my website , now i need to draw a diagram showing the tables and the relations , is there a tool that I can give my SQL backup the ( *.gz) and it generates the draws for me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio Express does quite good diagrams.

Comment: Attach your database to an SQL Server management studio and create new diagram, then add your table to it

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your database server (not your backup file) using [MySQLWorkbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), then use Database/Reverse Engineer to generate your model diagram